# Java - If statement logic error

Tags: java

The sequence of events should be:

> 1) I enter two.
>   2) I am prompted to choose a name.
>   3) I choose either Washington/ Franklin/ Hamilton.
>   4) I'm asked which denomination does this name appear on.
>   5) I give the answer.

However, when I enter Washington for part three - I am told that is an invalid number. I cannot see why this would be.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("Type 1 to enter a denomination, 2 to enter a last name");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = in.nextInt();

    if(x==1){
        System.out.println("Choose a denomination");
        int y = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        if(y==1){
            System.out.println("Which person appears on the 1 bill?");
            String answer = in.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("Washington")){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }


        else if(y==10){
            System.out.println("Which person appears on the 10 bill?");
            String answer = in.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("Hamilton")){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else if(y==100){
            System.out.println("Which person appears on the 100 bill?");
            String answer = in.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("Franklin")){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That is an invalid number.");
        }
    }
    else if(x==2){
       System.out.println("Choose a name");
        String y = in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        if(y.equals("Washington")){
            System.out.println("Which denomination does this name appear on?");
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            if(answer==1){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }


        else if(y.equals("Hamilton")){
            System.out.println("Which denomination does this name appear on");
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            if(answer==10){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else if(y.equals("Franklin")){
            System.out.println("Which denomination does this name appear on");
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            if(answer==100){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That is an invalid number.");
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem is with the x==2 segment. x==1 works fine.

Comment: Please post a [Short, Self Contained and Correct Example](http://sscce.org/), you can hide the working code and focus on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem **does not** lies with the seemingly extra `in.nextLine()`.

I will advise you to change all your `in.nextInt()` to `in.nextLine()` **followed by parsing them** to the actualy type such as `int`

**Example:**

```
int answer = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

**Reason for the suggested change**: When you use `nextInt()`, there is a tendency that nextline still lingers around there until you do an additional `nextLine()` to clear it.

To prevent this sort of problems, it is advisable to receive all inputs with `nextLine()`, then parse it to the actual type (`int`, `double`..etc).

This is also how ***Microsoft*** deals with integer input in `C#`.

---

**Edited Working Codes:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Type 1 to enter a denomination, 2 to enter a last name");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

    if(x==1){
        System.out.println("Choose a denomination");
        int y = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        in.nextLine();
        if(y==1){
            System.out.println("Which person appears on the 1 bill?");
            String answer = in.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("Washington")){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }


        else if(y==10){
            System.out.println("Which person appears on the 10 bill?");
            String answer = in.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("Hamilton")){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else if(y==100){
            System.out.println("Which person appears on the 100 bill?");
            String answer = in.nextLine();
            if(answer.equals("Franklin")){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That is an invalid number.");
        }
    }
    else if(x==2){
       System.out.println("Choose a name");
        String y = in.nextLine();
        //in.nextLine();
        if(y.equals("Washington")){
            System.out.println("Which denomination does this name appear on?");
            int answer = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if(answer==1){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }


        else if(y.equals("Hamilton")){
            System.out.println("Which denomination does this name appear on");
            int answer = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if(answer==10){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else if(y.equals("Franklin")){
            System.out.println("Which denomination does this name appear on");
            int answer = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
            if(answer==100){
                System.out.println("That is correct");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("That is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("That is an invalid number.");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I've tried parsing all the ints to nextLine ~in segment two x==2, however the problem still persists.

Comment: @PeterMarker I already tried it and is working perfectly at my side. Copy and paste my codes and try again.

Comment: @PeterMarker After you tried my codes, let me know if it works on your side.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the information, the kind of of issue I had isn't the type which I would have ever been thought. Should aid me a lot going forward.

Comment: @PeterMarker Yes, in future just receive input and parse it. There are no known side effects for doing this. If you use the additional nextLine() approach, there is still a tendency it may give you trouble which can cause you hours to spot the source of problem when you are unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String y = in.nextLine();
in.nextLine();
if(y.equals("Washington")){
```

You're calling in.nextLine() one too many times.  Remove that second line.

Comment: Ahhh. Due to the x==1 segment, I had the extra line. Forgot to remove it. Cheers

Comment: Hmm. Even when I remove the line, I get the "That is an invalid number" output before I even get to enter a name.

Comment: @PeterMarker Look at my solution, 100% can solve all your problems including your future problems of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

You have to skip the line after `nextInt()` then take user input(in `y==2` case) because `nextInt()` doesnot consume the whole line it consume the token.

```
in.nextLine();
String y = in.nextLine();
```

with your code the `in.nextLine()` in  `String y = in.nextLine();` is reading the same line where you entered value of `x` getting the value `y` to be `""` and hence the output `"That is an invalid number"`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `String y = in.nextLine()`, the next token is the leftover newline from the previous `nextInt()` call, so `y` ends up being equal to `\n`.

Place a call to `nextLine()` after you use `nextInt()`:

```
int x = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```

Afterwards you should be able to call `nextLine` only once when getting the user input:

```
String y = in.nextLine();
if(y.equals("Washington")){
```